# Passing the data from the Express API Parameter to Request Module in MEAN Stack

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I am facing below issue with passing the parameters from the Express API to Request module URL.

In the below code Suppose I have the request details as

`request_data.url = http://localhost:3000/interface/en/`

When users enters the URL as `http://localhost:3000/interface/en/123456`

I wanted to send the 123456 to the line

`url: request_data.url + acct,`

Hence my final url for the request module becomes as `http://localhost:3000/interface/en/123456`

But my below code is not working , can someone help me here or suggest me what changes are requires

> **Code**

```
app.get('/interface/:env/:acct', (req, res) => {
    var acct = req.params.acct;
    var env = req.params.env;
    var hsResponse = request({
        proxy: proxyUrl,
        url: request_data.url + acct,
        headers: request_data.headers,
        method: request_data.method,
        form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(body); //<-- send hsResponse response body back to your API consumer
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to update your url outside request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use following code,

```
              app.get('/interface/:env/:acct', (req, res) => {
                  var acct = req.params.acct;
                  var env = req.params.env;

                  // here you need to update your url
                  request_data.url = request_data.url + acct;

                  var hsResponse = request({
                      proxy: proxyUrl,
                      url: request_data.url ,
                      headers: request_data.headers,
                      method: request_data.method,
                      form: oauth.authorize(request_data)
                  }, function (error, response, body) {
                      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                      res.send(body); //<-- send hsResponse response body back to your API consumer
                  });
              });
```

I think you are using [OAuth](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a), where you passing form field to the [request](https://github.com/request/request#forms), which will need to authorize with existing mapped `request_data` like `URL` and other `attributes`.

Hope this will help you !!